# Access excel worksheet rows with passcode online

Tags: excel, phpexcel, excel-2013

I have an excel file which has more than 100 rows for each student in my class. Each row has the current points of a certain student and is named with his firstname_lastname. I wonder how I can put online and allow every student to only access his row using a passcode or something. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

You can do by saving all data in an excel file. But you have to think, how good this idea is. I give an example here.

Here I have 1234.xls file as shown below.

[image: Excel view]

Name is name, pass is pass code for access and data is the protected data.

Here is the html form for sending student name and pass code.

```
<form action="phpfile.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="student" />
<input type="text" name="passcode" />
<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Here the php code for phpExcel. I use version 1.8. I think the comments will clear your doubts if any.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['student']))
{
require_once 'PHPExcel-1.8/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
$inputFileName = './1234.xls';
try {
    $inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
    $objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
    $objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file "'.pathinfo($inputFileName,PATHINFO_BASENAME).'": '.$e->getMessage());
}
$sheet = $objPHPExcel->getSheet(0); 
$highestRow = $sheet->getHighestRow(); 

$student = $_POST['student'];
$pass = $_POST['passcode'];

for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; $row++)    //get all rows of name
{
    $rowData = $sheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue();
    if($rowData == $student)  //compare with user input
        {
        $passcode = $sheet->getCell('B'.$row)->getValue();   //get passcode of same student
        if($passcode == $pass)   //compare pass
            {
            $accessdata = $sheet->getCell('C'.$row)->getValue();  //get data
            echo $accessdata; 
            break;
            }
        }
}
}
?>
```

Comment: @Tak : I am not sure about the performance etc. This is a way I explained.

Comment: could you please show me the detailed steps as I don't know where to put the html form,...etc? Much appreciated

Comment: Where do you host the web?? Locally or on webserver??

Comment: The excel file is on a network shared drive, but I can put it online, any suggestions?

Comment: When you don't have much security consideration, keep HTML, php and the excel file in web root directory. @tak

Comment: I honestly didn't understand what you mean. Could you please explain further?